# Удалить пустые элементы массива

Tags: массивы, lua

Есть массив `ITEMS(item1=1,item2=2,item4=4,"",item10=10,"",item16=16)`

Вывожу его содержимое 
`print("массив ITEMS:",table.concat (ITEMS, ", "))`

Получаю: 
`1, 2, 4, , 10, , 16`

Как можно удалить пустые строки отсюда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ @Ainar-G работает некорректно для массивов, где два пустых элемента идут подряд. Есть два способа обойти это:

1. Сперва записать элементы для удаления, а после уже удалить их:

```
local a = { "a", "b", "", "c", "", "", "d" }

local function cleanupArray(arr, valtodel)
    local todelete = {}
    for k, v in ipairs(arr) do
        if v == valtodel then
            todelete[#todelete+1] = k
        end
    end
    for k, v in ipairs(todelete) do
        table.remove(arr, v-k+1)
    end

    return arr
end

cleanupArray(a, "")
print(table.concat(a, ", "))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBasMwDIbP1lOI7FKTdtAHyGHPMXZQHYWZuHJQncIoffbUjpvCoGAJWf/vT7bDTMsSoqOAhB3esKFmj82ppBJuK0r0Dd4BqnuYxSUfBV1gknn6UqW/Hanu8UohxZ6DBVO9644TlwF3MENUHLMNvaCfyOulnLPYRzDGD1nouhcE0y9L7psN8v2xVe3xJxPHLLL0UNMb9mZ/Dkh0CvypfI5Xft73MLZHWwFglNOsglmBtfH/feUnLEzqJe0qyUVxlFYlL2uX5QE)

2. Не менять индекс, если мы удалили элемент:

```
local a = { "a", "b", "", "c", "", "", "d" }

local function cleanupArray(arr, valtodel)
    for i = 1, #arr do
        ::begin::
        local v = arr[i]
        if v == nil then return end

        if v == valtodel then
            table.remove(arr, i)
            goto begin
        end
    end
end

cleanupArray(a, "")
print(table.concat(a, ", "))
```